# Validate ending letters only

Tags: javascript, validation

I want too validate endings "uu", "ha" and "cross" at the end of the words that users are going to type in... please see "//" in "script" tags of what I mean:)

Here's my html form:

```
<form name="myForm" action="haha.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    <p id="text">Something: </p> 
    <input type="text" name="form" id="box" >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="but" >
</form> 

<p id="check"></p>
```

And my java script validation...

```
function validateForm() {
    if( document.myForm.form.value == "" ) {
        document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = 'Please fill in the form:) '; 
        return false;
    } 

    //ok so here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve... 
    if( document.myForm.form.value == endings "uu" "ha" cross" ) --//please correct- endings "uu" "ha" cross" --    { 
        return true;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use regular expression to test that string ends with one of the given substrings:

```
if (/(uu|ha|cross)$/.test(document.myForm.form.value)) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for matching the *end* of the words. "Happy" returns true, since it contains "ha", for example. Maybe it needs the $ at the end of uu and ha also?

Comment: Maybe you mean `/(uu|ha|cross)$/`?

Comment: yeah mate that kind of a problem, do you know how to do it -Zack?

Comment: @aloha_mate use torazaburo's comment, it works for me here http://jsfiddle.net/abobfyfa/

Comment: @Zack What do you mean, there is `$` at the end. oh, that's right, missed `()` of course. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
if(submittedValue.slice(-2) == "uu" || submittedValue.slice(-2) ==  "ha" || submittedValue.slice(-5) ==  "cross" )     { 
    return true;
}
```